# Как сделать субтитры к видео, без субтитров?

Tags: html

При создании плеера столкнулся с проблемой:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>   <source src="forrest_gump.mp4" type="video/mp4">   <track src="fgsubtitles_en.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English"> </video>
```

Чтобы использовать этот код нужно иметь файл с субтитрами, но так произошло что субтитры **ВЛОЖЕННЫ В КОД ВИДЕО**, то есть субтитры есть в видео, а файла с ними нет (т.к. я его скачал)

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Файла нет, так как я его скачал, как резиновую женщину...